# Error al compilar el Flexible Client de Android, GeneXus 17 upgrade 3

Tags: android, genexus

Agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar.

Uso GeneXus 17 upgrade 3 generando .Net en el servidor. Instalé Java SDK 15.02, modifiqué el BTDeviceListActivity.java, y al compilar me da el siguiente error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17u3\Android\Sources>gradlew FlexibleClient:assembleRelease FlexibleClient:uploadArchives

C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17u3\Android\Sources>set genexus_home=C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17u3

C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17u3\Android\Sources>set android_home=C:\Android-SDK

C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17u3\Android\Sources>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2

Task :SqlDroidBase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17u3\Android\Sources\UserControlLibraries\SQLDroid-Base\src\main\java\org\sqldroid\SQLDroidConnection.java:415: error: An unhandled exception was thrown by the Error Prone static analysis plugin.
  public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> arg0) throws SQLException {
           ^
 Please report this at https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/new and include the following:

 error-prone version: 2.3.3
 BugPattern: TypeParameterUnusedInFormals
 Stack Trace:
 java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: bound
    at com.google.errorprone.bugpatterns.TypeParameterUnusedInFormals.matchMethod(TypeParameterUnusedInFormals.java:71)
    at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneScanner.processMatchers(ErrorProneScanner.java:433)
    at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneScanner.visitMethod(ErrorProneScanner.java:725)
    at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneScanner.visitMethod(ErrorProneScanner.java:150)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:925)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreePathScanner.scan(TreePathScanner.java:82)
    at com.google.errorprone.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:71)
    at com.google.errorprone.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:45)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scanAndReduce(TreeScanner.java:90)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:105)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scanAndReduce(TreeScanner.java:113)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.visitClass(TreeScanner.java:189)
    at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneScanner.visitClass(ErrorProneScanner.java:535)
    at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneScanner.visitClass(ErrorProneScanner.java:150)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:832)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreePathScanner.scan(TreePathScanner.java:82)
    at com.google.errorprone.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:71)
    at com.google.errorprone.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:45)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:105)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scanAndReduce(TreeScanner.java:113)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.visitCompilationUnit(TreeScanner.java:144)
    at com.google.errorprone.scanner.ErrorProneScanner.visitCompilationUnit(ErrorProneScanner.java:546)
```

Comment: Somos genios, no adivinos. Si no publicas el código (como texto), cualquier respuesta es pura especulación.

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser un error con error prone y jdk superiores al 13.
https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/1352

Puedes intentar con jdk 8 (default en v17u3 ) o 9?

Gracias,

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias , instale el 9 y compilo.